# Network bandwidth assesment tool

Tags: testing, networking, windows-ce

I need to test the bandwidth I have on my USB RNDIS connection. I am using windows CE 6.0.

I already tried looking into [iperf for windows ce](https://sourceforge.net/projects/iperfwince/), but, sadly, I did not manage to compile it.

Can anybody recommend of a tool/API to test the bandwidth under Windows CE?

In case the answer involves an API, I am looking for something with minimal effort (obviously)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you do something as simple as connecting to the other end (you didn't say if you want to test from the device side or PC side), pull some known-size file, and time the pull.  You then have bytes/time.

Comment: Doing this now. But, I'd rather have something automatic. Be it device side or desktop side. Thanks.

Comment: I just wrote a program that does this basically. Copies a file over the network and prints out the time it took to copy the file. Thanks for pointing out the obvious... I sometime miss looking at the obvious direction.